# find the second largest number in the given list [duplicant]

Tags: python

```
    b=list(map(int,input().split()))
c=max(b)
for i in b:
        if i == c:
            b.remove(i)
        else:
            continue
print(max(b))
```

where I am getting wrong with this code I am not getting correct output for input 6 4 5 6 6

Comment: You're also computing `max(b)` *every time through the loop*.  So your loop is O(n**2) rather than O(n).  But the specific problem is you're trying to modify `b` while iterating over it.  Don't.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `set` and `sorted()` to grab the second highest number in the list.

- Passing your `list` to a `set` will only include unique numbers
- We then sort the `set` and grab the second last element in the list

---

```
data = [6, 4, 5, 6, 6]
sorted(set(data))[-2]
#5
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Approach**

In this code, we are sorting the list `b` and then printing the second-last value using indexing

```
b=list(map(int,input().split()))
sorted(b)
print(b[-2])
```

Output:

```
6
```

**Second Approach**

In this approach, we are sorting the list, converting it to a set to remove duplicate values, converting the set again into a list and getting the second-last value

```
b=list(map(int,input().split()))
sorted(b)
final_b = list(set(b))
print(final_b[-2])
```

Output

```
5
```

Actually, the above codes can be written in a single line / fewer lines but it won't be easy for you to read if you are a beginner.

Comment: `sorted()` returns a list, there is no need to convert the set back into a list prior to sorting.

Comment: @PacketLoss yeah, i forgot about it. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = list(set(map(int, input().split())))
b.sort()
print(None if len(b) < 2 else b[-2])
```

`set` is used to delete duplicate values, and finally to determine if there are two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to use the nlargest method of the heapq module. it can be used to find the first n largest numbers

```
import heapq

data = [6, 4, 5, 6, 6]

heapq.nlargest(2, set(data)) # returns [6, 5]

# So we can unpack the values as below
_, second_max = heapq.nlargest(2, set(data)) # the '_' means we dont care about storing that variable

# Now print it
print(second_max) # Output: 5
```